# nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx

I'm having issues with my nginx server conf.

When I run `nginx -t` it says that everything is correct, but when I check my config file per file, it's KO.
It says :

> nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-available/thebishop.fr.conf:1

here some conf files :
nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    more_set_headers 'Server: 185.216.27.123';

    client_max_body_size 20M;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

thebishop.fr.conf :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name thebishop.fr www.thebishop.fr;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen               443 ssl;
    server_name          thebishop.fr;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/thebishop.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/thebishop.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    return 301 $scheme://www.thebishop.fr$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.thebishop.fr;
    root /var/www/html/thebishop.fr;

    index index.html index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/thebishop.fr_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/thebishop.fr_access.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/thebishop.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/thebishop.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    # if ($scheme != "https") {
    #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # } # managed by Certbot

}

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "check your configuration file by file" how do you do this? And why? Plus what does "KO" stand for?

The "server" directive is [only valid within an http blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server), so checking file by file is not going to work. So long as "nginx -t" works and nginx runs without errors I don't see a problem.

If I haven't answered your question please edit it to include more detail about exactly what you did including command line and output, Nginx errors, and remove abbreviations.

Comment: so I guess the reason why my server won't start lies somewhere else, I'll dig a bit or create a new topic since after all it's really related to this one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These two lines in `nginx.conf` are instructions to include all of the files in these directories in this order:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Try swapping them so that `thebishop.fr.conf` is definitely the next thing to be included.  You want:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only be running `nginx -t`

What you're doing is running a command that is designed to manually 'set' the nginx core config. That isn't designed to be used for checking included files, but for manually telling nginx where to find the `nginx.conf`.

Server blocks **must** be inside http blocks. Obviously, that file doesn't contain an http block because it's an included file.

Simply doing nginx -t is perfectly fine for what you're trying to achieve, and is 100% the correct way to test your config is correct.